# Wacom Graphics table shown but is not installed

Tags: scanner, wacom, graphics-tablet

On both my previous computer and this new one, "Wacom Graphics Tablet" appeared in my Hardware list.

I don't have this, never did.  The common (reused) hardware is:
- Samsung CLP300 printer
- Altec Lansing speaker set
- Microtek Scanmaker 4800 scanner
So I guess something is being confused.

I find the printer, but not the other two in the existing list.  It seems unlikely that the speakers would confuse it, even though the settings are correct and cannot be corrected.

So maybe the scanner is confusing it?  However, the scanner seems to work ok.

If I click on the tablet icon, it says "not detected".

Now what?

Thanks!

Comment: 'appeared in my Hardware list' Exactly where it appears?

Comment: It appears in "System Settings > Hardware", it's the last item listed.

Answer (score 0):

The **Wacom Graphic Card** appears in Ubuntu **installed or not**. The options to access to this device are enabled for default.

Not only happens with Wacom but the same happens with the **Printer** and **Bluetooth**. Basically with the most popular devices. In no OS of a PC will show a option like `Airbus's Devices` *I think.*

---

This topic reminds me the main functions of the OS, the abstracting of the user from the complexity of the hardware and manage the physical resources. This one is an example. You can see if the Wacom is plugged or not right there, and connect it via bluetooth.

Comment: So is there no way to hide it, as it can be confusing?

Comment: @RogerDavis AFAIK, you can't. *Sorry for the delay* :-)